# WebBrowser Control not added to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using WBC in my project but I don't need it to be added to the form, I tried to call Navigate method but still get empty string when retrieving

the WBC .DocumentTitle!

Comment: Can you post a code sample? Are you waiting for the document to finish loading before retrieving the title?

Comment: In case you'd just like to download files from the internet there are much more efficient possibilities, e.g. the `WebClient` class.

Comment: @evan Mulawski you could take a look at the code in the answer's comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate is asynchronous, that means it goes to that web page on another thread and does not wait until it finishes. You are trying to get the Title immediatelly, but it is not set yet.

You should attach to `DocumentCompleted` event on the WBC and check for title there.

Comment: I did that but dynamic event not fired!

Comment: webBrowser.Name = "mybrow"; webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Split); webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.site.com"); MessageBox.Show(webBrowser.DocumentTitle); public void  Split(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {  MessageBox.Show("Salam"); }

Answer (score 1):

As noted the title can only be retrieved after it has been set. To know when that happens, in addition to DocumentCompleted event there is also a [WebBrowser.DocumentTitleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttitlechanged%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event that is convenient and could simplify your logic.

Also, presumably, the latter event would also fire when title changes after the document is loaded via Javascript.

Comment: logical,but the problem was calling WBC .DocumentTitle just after WBC .Navigate().

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In any case, if you access DocumentTitle from within DocumentTitleChanged event handler, then the title value will be available.